# How to change rownames with same pattern of names

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub, mutate

Let's suppose I would like to change the names of rows in dataset, without varying the different characters

```
  mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(., var = 'Car')
```

For example:

1. where there is 'MERC' is wanted to be replaced with 'CERM'
2. where 'MAZDA' is wanted as 'ADZAM'

Is this here below the only available way?

```
mtcars %>% rownames_to_column('car') %>% 
  mutate(car = gsub('Merc', 'CREM', car), 
         car = gsub('Mazda', 'ADZAM', car))
```

Isn't there a more effective one? Thanks

Comment: Of course it's not the only available way. What do you mean by "more effective"?

Comment: Are you looking for a general way to extract the first word, change it to all caps, and reverse the order of the letters? Or is this process too slow and you need code that executes faster? Something else?

Comment: @George Thomas I mean not repeating everytime the car row in the mutate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the `stringr::str_replace_all` function as below

```r
library(stringr)

mtcars %>% rownames_to_column('car') %>% 
  mutate(car = str_replace_all(car,c('Merc'='CREM', 'Mazda'='ADZAM')))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>